# trying to simply query a mongodb database from swift app

Tags: swift, mongodb

I am trying to create a simple mac app that queries my local mongoDB.

I have a collection variable that I am trying to find multiple results on. For some reason I can not get it to work. The examples in the [mongodb documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/app-services/mongodb-remote-access/#find-multiple-documents) seem to be outdated.
My code looks something like this:

```
let year: Int = 2022
let buffer: Int = 1
...
let collection = mongodb.collection("holidays", withType: Holiday.self)
...
let queryFilter: BSONDocument = [
     "date_no_dash": [
         "$gte": BSON(integerLiteral: (year - buffer) * 10_000),
          "$lte": BSON(integerLiteral: ((year + buffer) * 10_000) - 1)
          ]
]
...
collection.find(queryFilter, session: mongoSession) { result in //<-- error on this row
switch result {
case .failure(let error):
  print(error)
  return
case .success(let documents):
  for doc in documents {
    print(doc.date_no_dash)
  }
}
```

On the `collection.find` row I keep on getting the error: `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. What am I overlooking? In general the entire "switch-handling" of the results seems cumbersome - isn't there a more elegant solution? Thanks for any input.

Comment: I don’t know mongodb but my guess is that the compiler doesn’t understand what you are returning from the closure since you have a return statement in only one of the code paths.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson tried adding a return to the `.success` case, but error still persists.